# Ubuntu server Supervisord doesnot restart

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu-16.04, supervisord, openedx

on the my openedx server i reboot my ubuntu server .After reboot my server down .
I understand from logs supervisord dont work . I think the downing is relating with it . Now i can not start it. When i want to start it this log returning :

```
Job for supervisor.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status supervisor.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

when i try systemctl status supervisor.service then i got

```
 supervisor.service - supervisord - Supervisor process control system
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/supervisor.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2018-12-15 11:44:40 UTC; 10s ago
     Docs: http://supervisord.org
  Process: 31345 ExecStart=/edx/app/supervisor/venvs/supervisor/bin/supervisord --configuration /edx/app/supervisor/supervisord.conf (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Dec 15 11:44:40 ip-172-31-14-220 supervisord[31345]:     handlers.append(RotatingFileHandler(filename,'a',maxbytes,backups))
Dec 15 11:44:40 ip-172-31-14-220 supervisord[31345]:   File "/edx/app/supervisor/venvs/supervisor/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/supervisor/loggers.py", line 172, in
Dec 15 11:44:40 ip-172-31-14-220 supervisord[31345]:     FileHandler.__init__(self, filename, mode)
Dec 15 11:44:40 ip-172-31-14-220 supervisord[31345]:   File "/edx/app/supervisor/venvs/supervisor/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/supervisor/loggers.py", line 98, in
Dec 15 11:44:40 ip-172-31-14-220 supervisord[31345]:     self.stream = open(filename, mode)
Dec 15 11:44:40 ip-172-31-14-220 supervisord[31345]: IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/edx/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log'
Dec 15 11:44:40 ip-172-31-14-220 systemd[1]: supervisor.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Dec 15 11:44:40 ip-172-31-14-220 systemd[1]: Failed to start supervisord - Supervisor process control system.
Dec 15 11:44:40 ip-172-31-14-220 systemd[1]: supervisor.service: Unit entered failed state.
Dec 15 11:44:40 ip-172-31-14-220 systemd[1]: supervisor.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
...skipping...
● supervisor.service - supervisord - Supervisor process control system
● supervisor.service - supervisord - Supervisor process control system
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/supervisor.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2018-12-15 11:44:40 UTC; 10s ago
     Docs: http://supervisord.org
  Process: 31345 ExecStart=/edx/app/supervisor/venvs/supervisor/bin/supervisord --configuration /edx/app/supervisor/supervisord.conf (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Dec 15 11:44:40 ip-172-31-14-220 supervisord[31345]:     handlers.append(RotatingFileHandler(filename,'a',maxbytes,backups))
Dec 15 11:44:40 ip-172-31-14-220 supervisord[31345]:   File "/edx/app/supervisor/venvs/supervisor/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/supervisor/loggers.py", line 172, in
Dec 15 11:44:40 ip-172-31-14-220 supervisord[31345]:     FileHandler.__init__(self, filename, mode)
Dec 15 11:44:40 ip-172-31-14-220 supervisord[31345]:   File "/edx/app/supervisor/venvs/supervisor/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/supervisor/loggers.py", line 98, in
Dec 15 11:44:40 ip-172-31-14-220 supervisord[31345]:     self.stream = open(filename, mode)
Dec 15 11:44:40 ip-172-31-14-220 supervisord[31345]: IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/edx/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log'
Dec 15 11:44:40 ip-172-31-14-220 systemd[1]: supervisor.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Dec 15 11:44:40 ip-172-31-14-220 systemd[1]: Failed to start supervisord - Supervisor process control system.
Dec 15 11:44:40 ip-172-31-14-220 systemd[1]: supervisor.service: Unit entered failed state.
Dec 15 11:44:40 ip-172-31-14-220 systemd[1]: supervisor.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I try dozen of ways on the internet but there is no use i can not handle please help me .

Answer (score 1):

I already have solved this problem. So the problem was related to folder ownership.So openedx uses some users for doing some works such as compile assets . Then it uses edxapp user or another user for another work. I gave the right permission for all of the folders. If you facing this error on Openedx . Firstly review your folder ownerships and group. Mainly /edx/var/log folder (Even you need the right chmod openedx user can write logs there)